# Not able to create object of SparkBundlecontext in mleap

Tags: apache-spark, noclassdeffounderror, mleap

I have imported required packages. I am even able to import SparkBundleContext

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.bundle.SparkBundleContext
```

But then when I do

```
val sbc = SparkBundleContext()
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/ml/clustering/GaussianMixtureModel
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven add the apache spark ML dependency as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are using SBT then add dependency as

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.1"
```

Use the right version of dependency so that it matchs your scala version.

Hope this helps!